# メタのバッジ一覧で金銀銅の丸ぽちが隠れている

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

URL: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

[image: バッジ]

Google Chrome 37.0.2062.124 / Mac OS X 10.9.5 / Retina

Comment: 同じ環境で見えないです。一回キャッシュを削除して、もう一回試したら？

Comment: 同じ環境で同様の現象が発生しています。

Comment: @jmac 開発者ツールでキャッシュを無効にしてリロードしても直りませんでした。`sprites@2.png`を`background-image`に設定している`.badge3`など用のCSSルールについて、`background-size: 220px 500px`に設定してみたら直りました。

Answer (score 1):

私の環境でも同様の現象が発生しています。
Safari 7.1 / Mac OS X 10.9.5 / Retina

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、メニューバーでも同様の現象が起きています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]